# Selection rules in Stark effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The energy level of an electron could be shifted by an electric field. $\langle n, l,m|[L_z,z]|n^{\prime},l^{\prime},m^{\prime}\rangle=(m-m^{\prime})\hbar \langle n, l,m|z|n^{\prime},l^{\prime},m^{\prime}\rangle$. Because $[L_z,z]=0$, we must have $m= m^{\prime}$ for non-vanishing $\langle n, l,m|z|n^{\prime},l^{\prime},m^{\prime}\rangle$. This is one selection rule in Stark effect.

Then how to rigorously prove $l^{\prime}=l\pm1$ is the other selection rule for $\langle n, l,m|z|n^{\prime},l^{\prime},m^{\prime}\rangle\neq0$?

Answer (score 1):

The key *physics* to keep in mind that you want to look at $\langle n,l,m|\mathbf{r}|n',l',m'\rangle$, because the electric dipole operator $\mathrm{p} \propto \mathrm{r}$.

Consider $[L^2, [L^2,\mathbf{r}]] = 2\hbar^2(\mathbf{r}L^2 + L^2\mathbf{r})$. If you equate the matrix elements of both sides of that, a lot of not very insightful algebra will give you the selection rule for $l$.

The only real physical insight I can give to explain why you would want to consider that particular commutator is that you want the matrix coefficients for $\mathrm{r}$, that the eigenvalues of $L^2$ will involve only $l$, and that evaluating the matrix coefficients of $[L^2,\mathrm{r}]$ won't give you an equation where you can set one side equal to zero.

Comment: $L_{\pm}$ can only change m.

Comment: @Jeremy, you're totally correct; my apologies. I have completely re-written my answer.